# Issue creating a large title navigation bar with 2 lines | Swift 5

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios14

Essentially I would like to create a double line large title navigation bar for iOS 14 - I cannot seem to find a conclusive answer anywhere.

The following is what I currently have:

```
title = "Good Morning \nTim"

for navItem in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
     for itemSubView in navItem.subviews { 
         if let largeLabel = itemSubView as? UILabel {
             largeLabel.text = self.title
             largeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
             largeLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
         }
     }
}
```

The issue with this is does display the second line, so the text is cutting off at Good Morning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be useful if you provide a photo how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewController needs this modification in viewDidLoad for example:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.textAlignment = .center
label.text = "Good Morning \nTim"
navigationItem.titleView = label
```